# Spring MVC with Sass

Tags: css, spring, model-view-controller, sass

I am working on a Spring MVC project and extending its capabilities to use Sass. I installed Sass correctly and verified that. I selected the compiler (Sass.bat) in the netbeans configurations but when I save the Scss file I don't find the output.

I know it's a file directory mapping issue. I tried several combinations of relative files URL but can't get it to work.

Thanks in advnace.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct path that should be for the scss files location:

/WEB-INF/resources/scss

and this for the css files generation location

/WEB-INF/resources/css